# Google Form redirect to different Pages based on field validation

Tags: validation, form-submit, response.redirect

I have a Google form and right now I can redirect the form to a Custom Page on Submit button. However, I would like to do validation on Submit button and redirect it to different page based on Fields. Is it possible. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that writing my own forms from scratch is sometimes easier than trying to hack Google Forms.   Some things like multi-page forms, redirect on required fields, etc take too much time to research / test.